# Why doesn't openSUSE Linux upgrade itself through its software repositories?

Tags: linux, yum, package-management, opensuse

openSUSE - fast becoming my favourite Linux distro on the client - doesn't seem to upgrade itself through its own configured software repositories.

Do we know why this is the case? Is it a money-making thing where they can then sell upgrade CDs / DVDs?

I mean, pretty much every other Linux upgrades itself through the normal software repositories. For example, Ubuntu can upgrade itself from 10.4 to 10.10 just through the normal software package upgrade procedure. Why must it be a huge procedure to upgrade openSUSE?

Any knowledge or ideas appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to OpenSUSE's documentation](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:System_upgrade) site you **can** upgrade between major release versions using just the online package repositories. This idea seems to be born out by several [other](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/opensuse/openSUSE/opensuse-reference/cha.update.html) [tutorials](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-upgrade-opensuse-11.2-to-11.3-desktop-and-server).

Comment: Hmmm, thanks. It looks like it *is* officially supported. Looks like a lot of hastle though - nowhere near as clean as Ubuntu or what-have-you. Time to change distro's methinks ;-) Thank you